# Do I need mutex in constructor for field?

Tags: c++, mutex

Let's assume I have a simple class A with one field in C++. This field is initialized in the constructor. Class A also has a method called `doit()` for modifing the value of this field. `doit()` will be called from multiple threads. If I have a mutex only in the `doit()` method, is this sufficient? Do I have a guarantee that I will never read an uninitialized field (because there is no lock in the constructor)?

**Edit:** I probably was not clear enough. Is there no issue involving processor cache or something similar? I mean, if there is no mutex for initializing memory region (i.e. my field)   - is there no risk that the other thread will read some garbage value?

Comment: I think you are confused.

++++++++
1. Each object has its own copy of the field and a constructor is called only once and it will initialize the field.
+++++
2. Each thread is has its on copy of the object then there is no need of a mutex.
++++++
3. In any case, even if the threads are sharing the object, the field is always initialised as the constructor was already called on such an object.

++++++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object can only be initialised once, and you won't be able use it before it's initialised, so you don't need a mutex there. You will however need a mutex or other suitable lock in your `DoIt` function, as you said this will be accessed across multiple threads.

**Update for edited question:** No, you don't need to worry about processor cache. You must construct your object first, before you can have a handle to it. Only once you have this handle can you pass it to other threads to be used. What I'm trying to say is, the spawned threads **must** start after the construction of the original object, it is impossible for it to happen the other way around!

Comment: OK, so 2 questions more:
a) so spawning a thread is a memory barrier (point in a program when memory is synced with cache)?
b) I do not understand your last sentence. I can pass handle of my object to running thread.

Comment: It's not a memory barrier, in order to use your object in a thread, the object must first be created. Then the created object is passed to the thread, who will perform operations (`DoIt`) on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to call `doit()` on an object that is not created yet, so you do not need mutex in the constructor.

If `doit()` is the only method that accesses the field, then you should be fine.

If other methods of your class also access that field, even from a single thread, then you must use a mutex also in these methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to construct the object before those pesky threads get their hands on it. The OS will allocate memory for the constructor that is only called by one thread. Ths OS looks after that allocation and therefore nothing needs to be done on your part. Hell you can even create two objects of the same class in two different threads.
2. You can be very conservative and use a mutex at the start of any method that used that field to lock it, and release it and the end.

Or if you understand the interactions of the various methods with the various algorithms , you can use a mutex for [critical sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) of code that use that field - i.e. That part of the code needs to be sure that the field is not altered by another thread during processing, but you method can release the lock after the critical section, do something else then perhaps have another critical section.